# 戻り値を設定したが、認識されずエラーがでてしまう。

Tags: typescript, chrome-extension

以下のコードがコンパイル時に「宣言された型が 'void' でも 'any' でもない関数は値を返す必要があります。」と怒られてしまいました。
なぜこのコードではだめなのでしょうか？
初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
function getTabId(): number {
  const tab = chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabArray) {
    const id: number = tabArray[0]["windowId"];
    return id;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず、ご質問のコード内には「function」が2つあります。
1つはgetTabId()の定義、もう1つはその{}内の処理中に書かれている無名関数『function(tabArray){}』です。
そしてreturnは無名関数の中にあるので、無名関数の方のreturnとして扱われてしまっています。

getTabId()の方のreturnとして扱いたいのであれば、無名関数の外にreturnを書かなければなりません。
以下は書き換えの一例です。

```js
function getTabId(): number {
  let id: number=0;
  const tab = chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabArray) {
    id = tabArray[0]["windowId"];
  });
  return id;
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
もう一つお聞きしたいのですが、chrome.tabs.query...は非同期処理で、id = tabArray...が実行される前にreturnされてしまい、思ったように動作しません。
awaitを使いたいのですが、awaitを使うと型がPromise<number>となって、型がnumberではなくなってしまいます。
こういうときはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながらjavascript/typescriptでは非同期処理を直接待機する方法がないので、getTabId()の戻り値の型をPromise<number>に変更せざるを得ないですね。chrome-extentionについては詳しく存じ上げず僭越なのですが、もしgetTabId()の実装部分を書き換えられるのであればgetTabId().then(function(id){...})の形で後続の処理を書いてみてください。